# Islam on big-bang

Tags: islamic-philosophy, belief, universe

I wanted to know does the thing we learn in schools and collages that our universe is created because of big bang. I wanted to know does islam support this believe and what's islam point of visw on hiw universe began?

Comment: Why would you think Islam does not support it? What does Islam even have to do with it? It's like asking does Islam support electricity or not.

Comment: Big-bang theory has not been proven yet - https://usm.maine.edu/planet/how-do-you-know-big-bang-occurred

Comment: See for example [Is there a contradiction about the age of earth with qur'an 21:30...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33708/is-there-a-contradiction-about-the-age-of-earth-with-quran-2130-the-heavens/33716)

Answer (score 0):

Assalamoalikum.

Yes, it does, the Qur'an says,

**"the heavens and the earth were joined together as one unit, before We clove them asunder" (21:30)**

One unit means the start, "singularity" in the big bang theory, all that was was joined as a unity, then Allah clove them asunder, i.e. the big bang (blast) itself.

So in my opinion, this verse clearly does talk about the big bang.

Answer (score 0):

as we know in big bang, the universe created by a very big explosion from a small dot then becomes very big.

in Quran (holy book for islam religion) there is a verse say **"the heavens and the earth were joined together as one unit, before We clove them asunder" (21:30)**

and after explode, as we know the universe getting bigger. Is already mention in quran in  **(51:47) We have made the heavens with Our own hands and We expanded it.**

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of all the flaws and points about the Big Bang theory, the problem seems to be that you think the Big Bang equals the absence of God, and even if we accept this theory, we have to keep in mind that The same small original mass also had a creator.